# Why does Python consider the self in a class as an argument I have to give

Tags: python, arguments, self

```
class combattant(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,img,posit):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=marche[0]
        self.image_pos=posit
        self.face=0
    def mov(self,direction):
        if direction[K_LEFT]:
            self.face=(self.face+1)%2
            self.image_pos.x -= 1
            self.image=marche[0+self.face]
            print ('gauche')
        if direction[K_RIGHT]:
            print ("droit")
            self.face=(self.face+1)%2
            self.image_pos.x += 1
            self.image=marche[2+self.face]

combattant.mov (tkey)
```

Here is my problem , when I run the programme containing this , I get this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\ISN\essai 2.py", line 63, in <module>
combattant.mov (tkey)
TypeError: mov() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Python seems to consider 'self' as argument that I need to give in order for it to work. I have tried using alpha functions or puting an empty space where the self argument is but of course I get an error saying 'Invalid Syntax' and the alpha function doesn't change anything ... Maybe I'm using this the wrong way because I'm a beginner ... It would be very helpfull if someone could help me ! Thank's in advance !

Comment: `self` is bound when you create an *instance* and call methods on that. If you are calling methods **directly on the class** then there is no instance to bind *to*.

Comment: You need to create an instance of `combattant` first, not directly access the methods on the class.

Comment: could help correct that error ?

Comment: should I run combattant () first ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to pass in arguments; what values should `img` and `posit` be set to?

Comment: I think I get what you mean ... I'll just have a try an keep U updated !

Comment: Ok so one big problem is that this programme was originally made to be used with Vector2 wich I tried to work without ... So I am now going to tryand redefine posit using the get_rect() method ... But not tonight !!! Thank's for your help  Martijn Pieters and Bryan Oakley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, when you call `combatant.move()`, you are calling move on the class, *not* on the instance of the class. The proper way to use that method is to first create an instance.

Typically, people name their class with an uppercase letter, and their instances with a lowercase, to make problems like this easy to spot.

For example:

```
class Combattant(...):
    ...
combattant = Combattant(...)
combattant.move(tkey)
```

The reason `self` is required, is so that the methods know which instance they are applied to. This makes it possible to have more than once instance of the class. When you call `some_instance.some_method(...)`, python will automatically add the `self` parameter when calling the method.

Comment: Ok so one big problem is that this programme was originally made to be used with Vector2 wich I tried to work without ... So I am now going to tryand redefine posit using the get_rect() method ... But not tonight !!! Thank's for your help  Martijn Pieters and Bryan Oakley